# Re-run code from specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work in Python 3. I want to make a contacts app with I/O. I want to re-run the code from specific line.

What is the best way to do that?

```
    #Contact

    Contact=input("Enter Name You Want To Save")
    f=open(r'C:\Users\Adham\Desktop\we.txt',"w")
    f.writelines(Contact)
    f.close()
    cont=input("write a for another name and l to load the previous save or close the program ")


    if cont=="a":
       Contact=input("Enter Name You Want To Save")
       f=open(r'C:\Users\Adham\Desktop\we.txt',"w")
       f.writelines(Contact)
       f.close()
    elif cont=="l":
      f=open(r'C:\Users\Adham\Desktop\we.txt',"r")
      print(f.readlines())

    else:
       print('sorry you made something wrong')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same code (slightly modified) multiple times, write a `function` and call this `function` every time, you need it.

A basic Python tutorial can be found here as an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm